# TensorFlow: CPU Choice AVX-512 AMD, Intel?

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, cpu-architecture

Most of my training is done using RNN , either LSTM or GRU, and I've found the CPU to be taking much of the load. 
I'm looking to put a new system together for testing, and I haven't seen any posts on which Architecture is more conducive to ML with TensorFlow. It seems it boils down to the Intel Core-X series having AVX-512 and AMD not (Specifically looking at i9-7900X vs Threadripper 1950X as they are a similar price).
So the question I have is two-fold:

1. Does TensorFlow make use of AVX-512 extensions, and
2. Are those extensions beneficial enough to make up for a 6-core deficiency of the 1950X -> 7900X

~ Are there any other considerations I am not taking into account? Any specialized performance optimizations that TF has made for Intel processors over AMD?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It's also primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Tensorflow really likes FMA throughput, doesn't it?  Intel CPUs with AVX512 have 4x the per-core per-clock FMA throughput of AMD, because AMD splits 256b FMA into two 128b uops, and each core has  two 128b FMA execution units.  But Intel has two 512b FMA units in each core.  Of course, saturating that takes a ton of memory bandwidth, and running 512b instructions shuts down the vector ALU on port1, so any real workload won't be as dramatic as that.  I have no idea how close Tensorflow comes to saturating the FMA units on Skylake-X for any kind of workload, so look for benchmarks.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have seen this for AVX, but I have never seen any mention of TensorFlow and AVX512 in the same article. The performance guide talks about some of the [Intel optimisations](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide). Every benchmark I have seen is about GPU performance, [except these which show the 1950X edging out](https://openbenchmarking.org/result/1708317-TY-1708274TY29&obr_sor=y&obr_sas=y&obr_hgv=Intel+Core+i9+7900X), but still no reason as to why . Which is why I disagree with you Ken - I am looking for Tensorflow data not opinion.

Comment: AVX512 may work: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4775.  The cache / memory architecture of SKX vs. Ryzen is significantly different, and that probably has a big impact, too.  (e.g. Ryzen has multiple L3 caches per cluster of cores, so sharing between clusters is slower).  You definitely need to benchmark a workload something like what you're doing on both CPUs to have any reliable comparison; extrapolating from profile results showing what the bottlenecks are on a Skylake or Haswell desktop would be hard (and you'd have to be a CPU-architecture / perf tuning expert).

Comment: Well I went the Intel route, I have yet to assemble, but once I do, I will compile with and without the avx512 gcc opt. 4.9 has avx512, but not 4.8, so I'll just ensure to use 4.9 or later, it isn't the world's most conclusive study, but as one of the key differentiators, it will provide a good datapoint for others, I'll post back here soon.

Comment: @ehiller Did you succeed in building TF with AVX512?

Comment: @ehiller What did you conclude?

Comment: @shibani sorry for that delay. The whole thing got postponed. I am actually just now getting back to it. I ended up doing the Intel processor though, I'm just not running tf yet.